# Permission denied error when opening Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, error, path

I'm using a clean install of 10.8. I wanted to add a couple of directories to my path. I tried adding them to /etc/paths using

```
sudo vim /etc/paths
```

Now when I open a terminal window I see this:

```
Last login: Wed Jan 23 15:42:57 on ttys001
/etc/paths: Permission denied
pcp067952pcs:~ myLoginName$
```

This doesn't affect usability, however it is something I would prefer to fix.

Any ideas?
-Austin

Comment: I believe you changed the permissions by editing the path with root privileges. My privileges for that file are `-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  105 Jun 26  2012 /etc/paths` I hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: Check by seeing what `ls -l /etc/paths` gives

Comment: oh! yeah i totally messed that up. i think i chmodded it to 0400. mine says -r--------  1 root  wheel  45 Jan 23 15:43 /etc/paths.

Answer (score 1):

solved by repairing permissions, thanks to jakebird451 and Mark in the comments above

i'm not sure is sudo is necessary, however this worked to fix it

```
sudo chmod 0644 /etc/paths
```

thanks!